# Erro ao gerar aplicação para android com unity

Tags: unity3d, android-sdk

Criei um "jogo" e estou querendo fazer *build* pra dispositivos android... mas to recebendo o erro:

> Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/Lucas/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Lucas/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o SDK e o Java instalado.
Como faço para funcionar?

Comment: É a primeira vez que tenta compilar?

Comment: Qual versão do SDK, 64bit ou 32bit?

Comment: Sim, eu compilei para PC e funcionou.. o problema é qando faço build pro andoid... e o sdk é 64bit

Comment: Tente copiar `c:\windows\system32\java.exe` pro `c:\windows\syswow64` por favor (onde `C:` é sua unidade do `Windows`)

Comment: N funcionou :-/

Comment: Tente instalar também a versão `32bit` do `SDK`

Comment: E se não funcionar, tente também copiar os `java.exe` das pastas de instalação do `Java` para `c:\windows\syswow64`. Por último, cheque se `JAVA_HOME` está nas variáveis de ambiente do seu OS (Windows ou Linux)

Comment: Dê também uma olhada nisto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501944/unity3d-android-build-error-win32-exception-zipalign

Comment: vai na pasta sdk e pesquisa por appt.exe quando achar copia para pasta tools